# joomla calendar function popup box

Tags: joomla, calendar

I am trying to get a calendar function to work:

```
 <label id="jform_issuedate-lbl" class="hasTip" title="Issue date::" for="jform_issuedate">Issue date</label>
 <input id="jform_issuedate" type="text" value="2013-09-25" name="jform[issuedate]" title="Wednesday, 25 September 2013">
 <img id="jform_issuedate_img" class="calendar" alt="Calendar" src="/media/system/images/calendar.png">
```

However when I use it in the site there is no pop up and no error is thrown.  It was working and now isn't.  I'm sure I must be doing something stupid and help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

I had this in before another bit of script and it seems it isn't compatible with the calendar function in joomla 2.5